# display density and resources usage (ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi)

Tags: android, android-layout

So I got HTC smartphone with 800x480 display. I always thought that it is HDPI device. And I was ensured using the following code:

```
Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
display.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
displayDensity = displayMetrics.densityDpi;
```

it says my device is 240dpi. But experimentally I'd discovered that android threats my device only as MDPI. Im sure bout this. I tested the same with another 800x480 (ZTE) and result was the same - it shows 240 in displayDensity but android threats it as MDPI device... But why is it so? On android.devepoler they said that 240dpi is HDPI. I'm totally confused. Why the heck 240 is threated as MDPI?

**How I'd discovered that android treats my HTC as MDPI device:**
In short what I made to ensure - I put a big image to drawable-hdpi (guessing AOS gonna use it) and smaller one to drawable-mdpi and than ran an app to see which it gonna use. And it always used image from drawable-mdpi instead of drawable-hdpi. To know how which image looks like on my device I ran app previously putting images to drawable folder of project.
However, like I mention above, I was guessing that my 800x480 HTC is HDPI due to code based on displayDensity but not on Configuration. Configuration says my device is Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL and seems like thats the reason why AOS treats my device as MDPI only. So in conjunction with DisplayDensity of 240dpi (which must be HDPI instead of MDPI) it really frustrating. So now the question is why with Display density of 240dpi Configuration sets device to MDPI type? Whats the reason of this? I was thinking that the one and only way to detect the device type is its display density. And if it is 240dpi it must be HDPI device instead of MDPI.

Comment: How did you determine that it gets treated as an mdpi device?

Comment: "But experimentally I'd discovered that android threats my device only as MDPI." -- please edit your question to explain **completely and precisely** how you tested this. More importantly, when you checked the `Configuration` `density` value -- which is what is used to determine the resources being loaded -- what did you learn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to read this page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html , it shows a complete explanation about screen density and others when you want to organize your resource folder.

About device being treated like MDPI it may be like Nexus 7, we were sure that it was MDPI, but it was using images from HDPI and also some values from MDPI/sw600dp (things that you will find better explained at that link above there), because its density, actually was TVDPI and so it's a 'middle' density between HDPI and MDPI. Try to download an app called ScreenInfo, on GooglePlay. It shows various informations about device screen, and may help you to make sure about your HTC.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I did read the article and thats a problem. And thanks for the tip I'll try that app

Comment: ScreenInfo says that "Framework resource selection" is "Normal/HDPI" for my HTC. I'm still confused is it HDPI or MDPI? Cuz it works in same way like you described it could use images from HDPI but layouts from MDPI. As for me this looks like a bug resource  "free to use by developers", like "Do you have any issues with your android app? Come and get this!"...

Comment: Since the device has this problem with its identity, but you now have sure that your HTC use images from HDPI, you should provide layout based on his screen size, not on its density, to avoid problems like this, also, it's one of that best practices, because you may have inumerous devices with same screen size, but with different densitys, so, only your images should be based on that, not your layouts. Have you tried to provide a layout based on its screen widht, for example? That link above shows how to do that.

Comment: So I created drawable-normal and my HTC uses drawables from there. This is sux cuz is can draw better images. If I gonna use drawable-wXXX folders I cant even imagine how many of such folders do I have to use. From where to start? With which step to go? Like should I start with w120? And then what? Next will be 130? 160? For me normal==MDPI but its not so for aos. This also means I should go with both dpi-folders and size-folders which means app size increasing even thou files in ldpi == files in small and so on. That means increasing app size x2 for nothing and then add here wXXX-folders...

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for delay, so, first of all, you have to decide which public you want. You have to keep in mind that there are inumerous devices around there and it's almost impossible to cover all of them. I'd advise you to start with devices considered normal(screen normal, and MDPI density) because that is the baseline. And then, worry about others, based on that first one. Understand that the differentiation on resources folders are only done if necessary. In most cases, resources used to baseline works well for everyone.

Hope it helps.