# Android Scaling & Density Issues

Tags: android, xamarin.android

**Update:** Some research has turned up that the Asus Transformer TF700T (high end) should have a pixel density of about 224, so the values of 159 android is reporting are either erroneous, or have been modified somehow (the lcd-density key in /system/build.prop), which I can't find for some reason.

I have two near identical tablets I'm developing on, both ASUS Transformer's, and both 10.1".

The higher end model has the following specs (where dm = ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics):

```
dm.Density = 1.5
dm.DensityDpi = High
dm.WidthPixels = 1920
dm.HeightPixels = 1128
dm.Xdpi = 159.8951
dm.Ydpi = 159.5811
```

and the lower end model has:

```
dm.Density = 1
dm.DensityDpi = Default
dm.WidthPixels = 1280
dm.HeightPixels = 752
dm.Xdpi = 160.1576
dm.Ydpi = 160
```

The higher end model has a discrepency. The Density/DensityDpi is 1.5/High, which makes sense b/c of the high resolution within a 10.1" screen. But to get a value of 1.5, wouldn't Xdpi/Ydpi = 240, such that 
(for equation, see http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

where

```
scale = (dpi / 160)
```

so

```
240/160 = 1.5
```

Xdpi/Ydpi of 160 doesn't correspond to a 1.5 Density (scaling) factor, which would be 160/160 = 1, correct ?

This discrepancy between the DPI's and scaling factor is causing me some size mismatches between the two tablets,
b/c the functions I'm using (Context.Resources.GetDimension) is scaling the values up too much on the higher end tablet (or too small on the lower end, depending on which I base the "normal/good" sizes on).

That is, I wouldn't have this problem if the Density was 1, or the xdpi/Ydpi was 240, on the first tablet. These values don't appear to be connected, as they should be. This may be because ASUS may have set the LCD-Density setting to 159, to obtain higher resolution (in /system/build.prop - I looked for the ro.sf.lcd_density key (with ROM Toolbox) to confirm but couldn't find it).

---

Here are some print outs for reference, from the custom view's constructor:

High end tablet:

```
Context.Resources.GetDimension(control_panel_height_id) = 75
Context.Resources.GetDimension(grid_cell_boarder_width_id) = 1.5
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_title_height_id) = 40.5
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_title_text_size_id) = 21
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_item_text_size_1_id) = 18
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_item_text_size_2_id) = 15
Context.Resources.GetDimension(month_label_text_size_id) = 33
```

Low end tablet:

```
Context.Resources.GetDimension(control_panel_height_id) = 50
Context.Resources.GetDimension(grid_cell_boarder_width_id) = 1
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_title_height_id) = 27
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_title_text_size_id) = 14
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_item_text_size_1_id) = 12
Context.Resources.GetDimension(list_item_text_size_2_id) = 10
Context.Resources.GetDimension(month_label_text_size_id) = 22
```

where the view's layout declaration is

```
<AppName.Droid.Views.Custom.CustomView
  xmlns:calendar="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/namespace"
  android:id="@+id/CustomView1"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#1100FF00"
  calendar:control_panel_height="@dimen/control_panel_height"
  calendar:grid_cell_boarder_width="@dimen/grid_cell_boarder_width"
  calendar:list_title_height="@dimen/list_title_height"
  calendar:list_title_text_size="@dimen/list_title_text_size"
  calendar:list_item_text_size_1="@dimen/list_item_text_size_1"
  calendar:list_item_text_size_2="@dimen/list_item_text_size_2"
  calendar:month_label_text_size="@dimen/month_label_text_size"/>
```

and the dimens it references are defined as

```
<resources>
  <dimen name="control_panel_height">50dip</dimen>
  <dimen name="grid_cell_boarder_width">1dip</dimen>
  <dimen name="list_title_height">27dip</dimen>
  <dimen name="list_title_text_size">14dip</dimen>
  <dimen name="list_item_text_size_1">12dip</dimen>
  <dimen name="list_item_text_size_2">10dip</dimen>
  <dimen name="month_label_text_size">22dip</dimen>
</resources>
```

Comment: You're calculating it wrong.  For the high end, 1920 / 160 = 12, i.e. 12 inches.  Divided by 1.5 ( the density multiplier) yields a width of 8 inches.  For the low end, 1280 / 160 = 8 inches, divided by 1 = 8 inches.  Do the same for height, use Pythagoras theorem and you get a 10 inch diagonal.  For your specific issue, I can't see why you're getting problems but  I've always relied on `WindowManager`.  I've never used `Resources.GetDimension`

Comment: @Simon They're both 10.1" (added to OP). Also, I'm not doing any calculations, just reading the ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics data structure. As you suggested, I probably shouldn't use Resources.GetDimension; I'll just reference the dimen's directly from the view's constructor, instead of assigning them as xml attributes in the layout file (and then having to read the attributes, which is where my problem arises), since that is howing I'm doing it in other parts of the app with no size mismatch issue's (that just dawned on me overnight). Thanks for comment, it did help me out.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I'm not accepting my own answered so that hopefully someone that knows what is going on with this will take a shot. I'm posting this answer b/c it did solve my problem, but still doesn't address some underlying questions and mysteries.

---

Well, after doing some calculations of my own, it looks as though the high-end device has more accurate Xdpi/Ydpi values, and the lower end device is reporting higher than calculated values.  Both have physical dimensions of

```
length = 7.12"
width = 10.35"
```

so, we have for the high-end tablet

```
Xdpi = 1920 / 10.35 = 185.5
Ydpi = 1128 / 7.12 = 158.4
```

and for the low-end one

```
Xdpi = 1280 / 10.35 = 123.7
Ydpi = 752 / 7.12 = 105.6
```

Asus documentation states that

```
dpi (high-end) = 224
dpi (low-end) = 149
```

I do realize that android "**buckets**" devices into 4 groups based on density: **low, medium, high, very-high**, and assigns the (abstract) dpi value (in /system/build.prop) with preset values based on these: **120, 160, 240, and 320** respectively.

Despite these values, android did correctly report the Density (scaling factor) for each, which was

```
Density (high-end) = 1.5
Density (low-end) = 1
```

So, as suggested by android (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for supporting multiple screens, I made two Values folders for two versions of dimens.xml (where the size's were defined):

```
Resources/Values-Hdpi/dimens.xml
Resources/Values-Mdpi/dimens.xml
```

and adjusted the values accordingly, where Values-Hdpi/dimens.xml had smaller values to compensate for the 1.5 scaling factor, and Values-Mdpi/dimens.xml had "normalized" values that get scaled by 1.  Both tablets now correctly display the correct sizes. **But, isn't that what the dp/dip metric is for, so that these separate value sets do not need to be explicitly defined ?**

Comment: Try the ScreenInfo app you could found on the PlayMarket (with yellow icon). Looks like you do something like I did. I mean you think that AOS chooses resources using DisplayMetrics but thats not true. There is also a Configuration. So for instance I was thinking that my HTC is HDPI for AOS since its really hdpi/240 by DisplayMetrics. But by Configuration its NORMAL. pls look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837469/display-density-and-resources-usage-ldpi-mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi maybe u'r gonna find it useful. So maybe one of your tablets must use res/large-mdpi and the other res/large-hdpi.

Comment: @Stan yep, sounds like you had exactly the same issue, thanks for the link... "So maybe one of your tablets must use res/large-mdpi and the other res/large-hdpi", yes, the above solution precisely states that is how I resolved this issue. In your linked post, the statement "android threats my device only as MDPI" can be quantified with  ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density  or ApplicationContext.Resources.DisplayMetrics.DensityDpi (print them out to see... Density = 1 & DensityDpi = "Normal" for Mdpi devices). Thanks.

Comment: then I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do something like I did. I mean you think that AOS chooses resources using DisplayMetrics but thats not true. There is also a Configuration. So for instance I was thinking that my HTC is HDPI for AOS since its really hdpi/240 by DisplayMetrics. But by Configuration its NORMAL. [pls look at stackoverflow.com/questions/15837469/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15837469/display-density-and-resources-usage-ldpi-mdpi-hdpi-xhdpi) maybe u'r gonna find it useful.
 
So maybe one of your tablets must use res/large-mdpi and the other res/large-hdpi.